# Numpy: Remove neighboring repeated subarrays in a 2x2 array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, unique

Alright, Im new to Numpy but I cant figure this one out so turning it over to the experts. I have a 2x2 table-array like the one below, and I want to "sequentially uniqify" the array. Sequence matters so if there is more than one of the same row arrays next to each other then they are reduntant and should be excluded (the sequence of the row-arrays also matters so [111,222] are to be considered different [222,111]). Framed in another way, I only want to keep the row-arrays whose left or right neighbor (or top/bottom as it looks like below) is different from itself (marked by * in the example below).

```
[[[492 105]
  [492 105]
  [492 105]*
  [492 106]*
  [492 106]
  [492 106]
  [491 106]*
  [491 106]
  [491 105]*
  [491 105]
  [491 105]
  [492 105]*
  [492 105]
  [492 105]]]
```

I tried the numpy.uniquify function but that didnt care about the fact that I had a 2x2 array and instead returned each unique number inside each sub-array in a flat list which I dont want, and it sorted and changed the order of my original arrays which I also dont want.

With a simple for-loop I could have easily written out the logic of this, but I need this to be optimized at Numpy speed. The closest Ive gotten is to return a trutharray marking the spots where the left-neighbour is different, which seems to be working:

```
MYARRAY = numpy.matrix(  my2x2array  )
indexes = numpy.arange(len(MYARRAY))
trutharray = numpy.any(MYARRAY[indexes]!=MYARRAY[indexes-1], 1)
```

However, Im not sure how to proceed and what to do with the trutharray. Tried serving the trutharray to the numpy.extract function but this only returns a flat list of each subarray and doesnt even return all the elements that it should; in the case of my example it returned "[105 492 492 106]".

Any help? How can I proceed with my example and end up with unique sequential subarrays? Or are there any faster solutions for this problem? Numpy is very confusing to me at this stage :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
>>> a=array( [[492, 105],
...   [492, 105],
...   [492, 105],
...   [492, 106],
...   [492, 106],
...   [492, 106],
...   [491, 106],
...   [491, 106],
...   [491, 105],
...   [491, 105],
...   [491, 105],
...   [492, 105],
...   [492, 105],
...   [492, 105]]
... )
>>> g_idx=any(a[1:]!=a[:-1], axis=1)
>>> vstack((a[:-1][g_idx][0], a[1:][g_idx]))
array([[492, 105],
       [492, 106],
       [491, 106],
       [491, 105],
       [492, 105]])
```

That `a[:-1][g_idx][0]` is necessary or otherwise the first element will be missing.

Comment: `a[:-1][g_idx][0]` should be `a[0]`.

Comment: @CT Zhu, thanks a bunch for the quick and straightup solution; it looks correctish, but not entirely. I printed out the results from the vstack operation and found that the output returned subarrays with varied lengths, but I need the subarrays to be in the original subarray (always 2 integer items). That is: for my original example your code returned: `[[492 492 491 491]
 [492 491 491 492]]`. Only the left side of my subarrays are returned.

Comment: @BiRico, changing to a[0] resulted in an error, and so does changing to a[0]: 
`return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_2d,tup),0)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0`

Comment: Maybe I'm giving wrong information about what my `a` input array looks like. I used `print a` and got `[[492 105]
 [492 105]
 ..(middle omitted for clarity)..
 [492 105]
 [491 106]]`. 

`a` was constructed from two 1D arrays "newxs" and "newys" with this code `numpy.matrix(numpy.dstack((newxs,newys)))`

Another potentially relevant info is that my Numpy version is only v1.3. Your guys' help is awesome btw :)

Comment: Nevermind, @CTZhu your answer was indeed correct. It wasnt working for me bc I had misunderstood my array; my array of arrays was already listed inside another array `[[[x,y],[x,y]...]]`. So all I had to do was to change my array correctly, and your answer worked perfectly, thanks and +1 to you! The a[0] part also worked BiRico.

Comment: @CTZhu although your answer worked and is quite fast, I have code that I need to be super fast and your suggested numpy operation which is used many times in my script is part of the bottleneck. Is there a faster way (better speed-performance) to get the same results, that you can think of? I dont mind if it requires more lines of code. Thanks either way :)

Comment: @KarimBahgat, I am not sure, since you still have to do pairwise comparisons for each 'row', that's a lot of comparisons we are talking about. Do you think the problem can be further simplified that in the final result you only have the unique rows? i.e., if a row exist before it will not be picked the 2nd time? like the `[492, 105]` in the example? In that case a faster one is possible by using `np.unique()`

Comment: @CTZhu, I totally forgot to answer this one. No, the pairs cannot be entirely unique unfortunately because the coordinate pairs are geographical polygon coordinates, which means it matters if the polygon later returns to one of its previous path points. I've sort of accepted that this might be the fastest solution with Python/Numpy. And you guys have definitevely helped me speed things up. It is good enough for now but in the future I'll probably experiment with doing the transform in cython c-code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be marginally faster than the solution posted above; it eliminates an unnecessary array creation by preallocating it, and it treats the loop over the last axis to check if all elements are different in a faster manner with some voidview voodoo. But unless im missing something, the posted solution should be close to optimal, and rather trivial; I have a hard time believing that this is indeed the bottleneck in your code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[492, 105],
  [492, 105],
  [492, 105],
  [492, 106],
  [492, 106],
  [492, 106],
  [491, 106],
  [491, 106],
  [491, 105],
  [491, 105],
  [491, 105],
  [492, 105],
  [492, 105],
  [492, 105]])


def voidview(arr):
    """view the last axis as a void object."""
    return np.ascontiguousarray(arr).view(np.dtype((np.void, arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[-1]))).reshape(arr.shape[:-1])

q = voidview(a)
I = np.empty(len(q), np.bool)
I[:-1] = q[1:]!=q[:-1]
I[-1] = True
print a[I]
```

Comment: Thanks for this @EelcoHoogendoorn, but as you said, the improvement was only marginal. +1 for the creative solution though :)

Comment: This is one of the bottlenecks bc my main task is to draw/render many large polygons to a picture, and I've sort of wrestled the coordinate to pixel transformation away from the renderer and doing it manually in numpy, which I've found is faster. So barely 1 second is used for the actual rendering, vs 30ish seconds for coordinate-to-pixel transformation (we're talking about really large collections of polygons). And this uniqueifying part of the transformation takes up about 40% of the transformation time. The other major bottle is the actual calculation on the numpy array.

Comment: Are you writing a software renderer in python? You are going to need more than marginal improvements then, yeah ;). Perhaps I am missing something, but why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Hehe, well for my own sake and others I'm trying to write a simple yet fast Python-based package that people can use to view/create maps of geographic data. I have asked myself if I'm in over my head, but yet I find it is sort of needed, since PIL, Aggdraw, Matplotlib(based on Aggdraw), and even PyCairo (if I used it correctly) are all slower than my current approach (using numpy to minimize the vertexes to process) and require significant technical skills. Haven't tried Mapnik yet but it is supposedly based on Pycairo. Also I personally dislike how heavy/complex QGIS is so I'm makin my own :P