# Calculating long expressions using Numpy (coordinate transform)?

Tags: python, numpy, expression, coordinate-transformation

In Pythons Numpy module, is there a function that can calculate long/advanced math expressions on an array? I heard of the numexp module but want to stay clear of further dependencies.

Better yet, can I limit these expressions to only say the first or second element of the sub arrays within my array, without having to unpack them as separate arrays?

Here is my specific problem. I have an array of arrays containing geographic point coordinates looking like this: [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],etc...]. What I want is to transform these geocoords to pixel coordinates so they can be drawn on an image. I therefore want to run the following expression/calculation on the first element of each subarray, ie the xs:

`((180+X)/360)*screenwidthpixels`

And on the second element, ie the ys:

`((-90+Y)/180)*-screenheightpixels`

These expressions would work in a python for-loop but is too slow, which is why I'm turning to Numpy. I know I can and have tried to just link numpys single math operator functions after each other but still too slow, and besides, to do that I first had to unpack all the xs and ys to separate arrays and repack them together after the calculation making it even slower.

So I guess I'm looking for a more direct Numpy way using less steps to transform my coordinate array using the expressions above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
points = np.random.rand(10,2)
translation = np.array([180,-90])
scaling = np.array([1024, -768]) / np.array([360,180])
transformed_points = (points + translation) * scaling
```

This will do what you are looking for. It relies on numpy broadcasting rules to achieve expressiveness and performance.

But rather than explaining exactly how that works, I think you are better off finding yourself a good numpy primer, and starting at the top. numpy is one of the best things about python, and you cant go wrong learning a little more about it. Suffice to say, numpy is certainly up to the kind of task you are facing.

Comment: Nice! Although the previous answers would have been acceptable for my purposes, your solution makes the calculations and my overall rendering time 20-30% faster. Very stratightforward and works straight on the input list, so also spares the extra time it wouldve otherwise taken to retrieve the xs and ys memory views. That is, rendering time for 200 000 complex polygons from gadm.org now decreased from 45 secs to 35 secs. Thanks a bunch @EelcoHoogendoorn! I could never have thought of it myself.

Comment: Btw, maybe you could check out my other numpy-related post here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892153/numpy-remove-neighboring-repeated-subarrays-in-a-2x2-array) and see if you get any ideas for faster alternatives than the accepted answer, bc that part of my code is still a major bottleneck.

Comment: Hmm, alot of questions here, but if you don't mind, what would be a quick implementation of enabling zooming to a view extent (or just by a factor and centerpoint if easier) based on your answer above? Tried different approaches but cant get it to work consistently. I know how to do it with normal math expressions, but it gets a little blurry when its all in arrays. I suspect one of the width/height arrays just have to be decreased and an offset value would have to be added or subtracted somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused because I'm not sure exactly what you're saying you already tried, or what the speed condition for success is.

Are you saying you already tried something like the following, but it is too slow?

```
arr = whatever
arr[:,0] = (arr[:,0] + 180) / (360 * screenwidthpixels)
arr[:,1] = 180 - (arr[:,1] - 90) / (180 * screenheightpixels)
```

Comment: I had not tried the [:,0] syntax to select a subarray, nor did I know I could use normal Python math operators directly on numpy arrays. I had previously "unpacked" the subarrays with `xs, ys = incoords.T`, and used the numpy.subtract/multiply/etc operators. But when I tried your suggestions it was still as slow as my previous approach, and I got some unexpected behavior after repeated calls to [:,0], so keeping with the old way. Any alternative approaches?

Comment: Oh and regarding speed condition for success, currently on my computer an array of ca 1000 xs/ys takes about 0,00013 seconds, and if possible I'd like to cut it down to one tenth of that (0,00001), or at least half (0,00005). It really adds up for large number of computations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "having to unpack" to X and Y. Here's how you avoid unpacking (if i understand...)

```
arr = np.array([ [x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3] ])
arr.shape
=> (3, 2)
X = arr[:,0]  # fast, creates a view
Y = arr[:,1]  # fast too
((X+180)/360)/screenwidthpixels
```

Further speed up can be achieved by rewriting/simplifying your expressions.

```
((X+180)/360)/s       =>  (X+180)/(360*s)
(180-((Y+90)/180))/s  =>  (180/s-1/(2*s)) - y/(180*s)
```

In the first rewrite, you get 2 traverses of the array, instead of 3, and in the second, the array is only traversed twice, instead of 4 times.

Comment: Correct, by "unpacking" I meant creating new arrays of the xs and ys by calling `xs, ys = incoords.T`. Your [:,0] and [:,1] does the equivalent, but it turns out when I tried them there was no considerable speed difference and some other odd behavior, so Im staying with my original approach. Are there any similar but alternative approaches of getting subarrays, and/or faster math operations?

Comment: +1 for the tip about simplifying the expressions btw, I wouldnt have thought of that. Unfortunately I noticed afterwards that the expressions I provided were wrong. For the correct equations (updated in the question above) I used an online equation simplifier and found that only the second equation could be optimized. Is there some fast coordinate transform function in numpy perhaps instead of having to do all these traversals?

Comment: @KarimBahgat - Just FYI: Operations like `x, y = coords.T` or `x, y = coords[:,0], coords[:,1]` don't create new arrays. They're just "views" into the original array.  No additional memory is used (ignoring a few extra bytes for new python objects) and the operation is very, very fast.

Comment: Good to know, I thought coords.T returned two new arrays. That explains why coords.T was about as fast or faster than coords[:,0] and coords[:,1]. But when you call coords[:,0] = ... does that change that particular part of the array and store the change? Is that also the fastest way to change an array (vs only viewing it)?

Comment: The first equation certainly *can* be rewritten in a more efficient way, i.e. a way which only traverses the array twice.  Instead of spending a lot of time trying to speed things up "manually", if that's an option, use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), and its `autojit` decorator. Super-speed guaranteed.

Comment: As much as I love numba, it is hardly called for here; and a beast of a dependency as far as distributability is concerned

Comment: I havent heard of numba before, but I think as @EelcoHoogendoorn pointed out that it sounds like it would be a heavy dependency with many potential error messages, especially because I am planning to pack my program in a GUI via a .exe packed with pyinstaller. But thanks anyway, I did ask for speed, and sounds like its pretty good at that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [235]: xs=arange(1000)

In [236]: ys=arange(1, 1001)

In [237]: a=array([xs, ys]).T

In [238]: a
Out[238]: 
array([[   0,    1],
       [   1,    2],
       [   2,    3],
       ..., 
       [ 997,  998],
       [ 998,  999],
       [ 999, 1000]])


In [240]: a[:, 0]=(a[:, 0]+180)/360/1024
```

the `a[:, 0]` offers a view of the first column of `a`, it's fast and memory saving. [docs for numpy here](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/index.html)